# SQL Error #1022 Can't write; duplicate key in table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm getting a 1022 error regarding duplicate keys on create table command. why?

```
create table Tratta (
        id_tratta int(11) auto_increment,
        Prezzo int(11) not null, /* cambiare valore prezzo */
        Contributi_aggiuntivi int(11) not null,
        N_volte int(1) check(value>0),
        Andata_ritorno enum('a','ar') not null,
        fk_utente int(11),
        foreign key(fk_utente) references Utente(id_utente)
        on update cascade on delete no action,
        primary key(id_tratta)
        ) engine = InnoDB;
```

Comment: What server software are you using?

Comment: apache and i use phpmyadmin

Comment: I mean what _database_ server?  MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

You gotta check if there is another foreign key with the same name as the one u use in your table, in your entire model...